# Force VSCode to always use tab as indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatter

When I save files in VSCode, they are automatically formatted. Tab characters are converted to four spaces. But I prefer tabs. How can I force VSCode to use tab characters instead of four spaces?

These are my settings.

```
{
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "-ExecutionPolicy",
        "Bypass"
    ],
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "typescript.format.semicolons": "remove",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.insertSpaces": false
}
```

What setting am I missing to force VSCode to **not replace tab characters with 4 spaces**?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the settings editor, search for "indent" to find "Editor: insert spaces".

(This can be overridden on a language basis as well.)

Comment: Thanks! But my settings.json already has the `"editor.insertSpaces": false` line. This should disable the tab-to-spaces-replacing, I presume. It doesn't work for my Python files, for some reason...

Comment: @gromit190 See the note in the settings: having space/tab detection on will override this.

Comment: `"editor.detectIndentation": false` - space/tab detection is off

Comment: @gromit190 Check these settings are not overridden for Python. If they are not you might be hitting a bug (which might be language integration specific), Try asking in the issue tracker for the VS Code Python integration.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: @gromit190 It is all in your `settings.json` (the settings editor has a button to open the underlying file: top right in the UI). (Note, as [Python's style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) says use spaces, it is possible the integration overrides your tab/space setting.)

Comment: Thanks! The settings must be overridden by Python style guide. Is there any way to configure the style so that it use tabs instead of spaces?